# RPi 3B+power issue on GPIO port 1 +5.25 V

Tags: pi-3b+

I would like to ask for some help with RPi 3B+. It was working for three weeks and for some reason not starting anymore. I tried to wait for three day long as suggested for the polyfuse to rebuild, but nothing again. What I did before one program that I use for is reef-pi, and because my temp sensor sensed the wrong temp, I try to pull out and re plug the wire, (3.5 mm stereo jack) when I did that the RPi get shorted on some way, and now I can not restart anymore.

I have tried with two new SD cards but nothing improves. I have measured GPIO port pin 1 and I got the 5.25 volt. What does that mean? Is the RPi working or just something else?

This is my second RPi, the first RPi's SD card slot just fell off the board.

Comment: Do you have a monitor connected  or can you just observe green "SD access" LED flashing when booting?

Comment: monitor connected but no sd green led flashing

Comment: OK, now for stupid question . Is the red LED on ? No green LED activity  means no reading of SD. Do you  have a spare SD to load clean OS onto it? SD go bad and there is not much to do to recover them.

Comment: yes the red led is on and i try 3 different sd card,+usb stick

Comment: Sounds like you toasted it.

Comment: The fact that you shorted out something (did you?) tells me that the Pi may be very toast. Sending that much voltage and current to nanometer-scale transistors isn't really a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If pin 1 is measured at 5V the Pi is damaged beyond repair.

Pin 1 should be 3V3 and is used to power the SoC which will now be dead.

https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: pin 1 is 5v on gpio right side

Comment: Right side relative to what? Pin 1 is https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin1_3v3_power and it's 3V3. Are you sure you're not measuring physical pin 2?

Comment: @Dirk: pin 1 is the one with the square (as opposed to round) pad.

Comment: you r right pin 1 i call but that is pin2.Physical pin

Comment: @Seamus - yes I know my Pi pins... I'm asking OP to make sure he has the right one, not asking for 3rd party clarification

Comment: @jsz so you're actually measuring on physical pin 2?

Comment: Dear all, please be reminded of the "be nice" policy. I would think that Seamus' comment was posted in good faith and might actually be helpful to the OP. @jsz it would be most helpful if you could stick to the pinout and pin numbering as linked in the answer. Otherwise it's highly confusion and leading to an unneccesary back and forth in the comments section.

Comment: Please be careful when you're using a meter to check the Raspberry Pi pins. It's very easy to short two pins next to each other, which could zap your Pi. I use breadboard connectors so that I can take just the two pins I want to measure away. I'm now thinking I will make a pair of test leads with the proper connectors so that I don't have to connect wires which I then measure.

Comment: yes Dirk i measured pin#2 Physical pin.Sorry for that false info.And i measured the pin as NomadMaker writed down with breadboard connectors.

Comment: @jsz You need to edit your question to include the correct information.  That will stop people wasting their time in answering a wrong question.

Comment: Hi i could make shorter?if my gpio pin #2 have 5.2 v my board is working ?